# fetchUuidWithSdp always giving the cached UUID

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, uuid

i am writing an app in which i have to do a service discovery on a selected device, but whenever i am doing a fetchUuid it is always giving me the cached UUIDs on the remote device.

here is what i am trying

```
public boolean UUIDsearch(BluetoothDevice device){

    t=device.fetchUuidsWithSdp();
    Log.d(TAG,"Device class = :"+device.getClass());



    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

          String action = intent.getAction();
        //BluetoothDevice deviceExtra = intent.getParcelableExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE");
          if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID.equals(action)){
             uuidExtra =intent.getParcelableArrayExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID");
          }
          Log.d(TAG,"SDP has no errors: = "+t);
         // if(found==false){
          for(int i=0;i<uuidExtra.length;i++){
              Log.d(TAG,"UUID:   "+ uuidExtra[i]);
              if((uuidExtra[i].toString()).equals(MY_UUID.toString())){
                  found=true;
                  Log.d(TAG,"Match found in loop");

              }

          }
         // }
      }
  };



  // Register the BroadcastReceiver

  IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID);
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);

  return true;

}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code.

here is the logcat:

this is the error when it starts descovery:

```
 09-05 15:05:15.906: D/(32591): bta_jv_start_discovery_cback: p_sdp_rec:0x52ab0e4c
 09-05 15:05:15.906: D/BTIF_SOCK(32591): jv_dm_cback: event:8, slot id:26
 09-05 15:05:15.906: E/BTIF_SOCK(32591): ## ERROR : jv_dm_cback: BTA_JV_DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT, slot id:26, found channle #, status:0, scn:7##
 09-05 15:05:15.906: I/(32591): BTA_JvRfcommConnect
 09-05 15:05:15.910: D/BluetoothSocket(2100): inputStream.read ret: 4
 09-05 15:05:15.910: D/(32591): releasing SDP rsp_list
```

after the above error occurs fetchUuidWithSdp() returns the intent with cached UUIDs as error

```
 09-04 16:54:51.851: I/(24860): BTA got event 0x206
 09-04 16:54:51.851: I/(24860): btif_dm_search_services_evt:  event = 2
 09-04 16:54:51.851: D/(24860): btif_dm_search_services_evt:(result=0x0, services 0xa42ed8f)
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 0 uuid:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 1 uuid:00001103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 2 uuid:0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 3 uuid:00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 4 uuid:00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 5 uuid:00001110-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 6 uuid:00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.851: E/(24860): Index: 7 uuid:0000111b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 8 uuid:00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 9 uuid:00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 10 uuid:0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 11 uuid:0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 12 uuid:00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: E/(24860): Index: 13 uuid:00001400-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: D/(24860): btif_dm_search_services_evt Remote Service SDP done. Call bond_state_changed_cb BONDED
 09-04 16:54:51.855: D/(24860): bond_state_changed: state=2 prev_state=1
 09-04 16:54:51.855: D/(24860): HAL bt_hal_cbacks->bond_state_changed_cb
 09-04 16:54:51.855: I/(24860): bta_dm_search_sm_execute state:3, event:0x206
 09-04 16:54:51.855: D/(24860): bta_dm_search_cmpl
 09-04 16:55:59.703: E/BluetoothRemoteDevices(24860): aclStateChangeCallback: State:DisConnected to Device:00:0A:3A:64:A7:34
```

the above UUIDs are tagged as errors because fetchUuidWithSdp returns cached UUID when an error is encountered in the service discovery or it is taking a long time to do the same.

Comment: Can you tell me for what purpose you need UUID?So that I can help you

Comment: I am having a set of UUIDs and will have to see if that device supports all or not , if it does then only connect to that device.this makes my application to connect to a unique device that has the UUIDs , because i will be adding some randomly generated UUIDs on the remote device.

Comment: Did you ever come across a solution? I am getting similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but it's first result in my Google search about Android and cached UUIDs in the Service Discovery Protocol (SDP)

Android cache the SDP UUID records for devices together with the Bluetooth address of the device, so if you change the UUID for you service but not the Bluetooth address of the device, Android will still have the old cached UUID in the list of UUIDs when calling getUuids() on the device.

The only way to get rid of the cached UUID records is to reset Network settings in the Android system settings. It doesn't seem that it's possible to clear the cache programatically.